# Hive query failed with org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezTask java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, hdp, apache-tez

I have a `Hive Table` in `ORC` format, where:

- My table is partition by: Year + Month + Day.
- Total file size in HDFS: 10TB.
- Total records: 21 Billion records.
- Total data nodes in HDP: 8

I used `Zeppelin` notebook to query the table using `jdbc(hive)`

```
SELECT `timestamp`, url FROM events where id='f9e43fc7b' ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC
```

However, the query runs into below error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezTask.
Vertex failed, vertexName=Map 1, vertexId=vertex_1591402457216_0009_2_01, diagnostics=[Vertex vertex_1591402457216_0009_2_01 [Map 1] killed/failed due to:ROOT_INPUT_INIT_FAILURE, 
Vertex Input: evt initializer failed, vertex=vertex_1591402457216_0009_2_01 [Map 1], java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.util.regex.Matcher.<init>(Matcher.java:225)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.matcher(Pattern.java:1093)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.AcidUtils$BucketMetaData.parse(AcidUtils.java:318)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.AcidUtils$BucketMetaData.parse(AcidUtils.java:332)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.AcidUtils.parseBucketId(AcidUtils.java:367)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat.determineSplitStrategy(OrcInputFormat.java:2331)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat.determineSplitStrategies(OrcInputFormat.java:2306)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat.generateSplitsInfo(OrcInputFormat.java:1811)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat.getSplits(OrcInputFormat.java:1939)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveInputFormat.addSplitsForGroup(HiveInputFormat.java:522)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveInputFormat.getSplits(HiveInputFormat.java:777)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.HiveSplitGenerator.initialize(HiveSplitGenerator.java:243)
at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.RootInputInitializerManager$InputInitializerCallable$1.run(RootInputInitializerManager.java:278)
at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.RootInputInitializerManager$InputInitializerCallable$1.run(RootInputInitializerManager.java:269)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1730)
at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.RootInputInitializerManager$InputInitializerCallable.call(RootInputInitializerManager.java:269)
at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.RootInputInitializerManager$InputInitializerCallable.call(RootInputInitializerManager.java:253)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask$TrustedFutureInterruptibleTask.runInterruptibly(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:108)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.InterruptibleTask.run(InterruptibleTask.java:41)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask.run(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:77)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
]Vertex killed, vertexName=Reducer 2, vertexId=vertex_1591402457216_0009_2_02, diagnostics=[Vertex received Kill in INITED state.,
Vertex vertex_1591402457216_0009_2_02 [Reducer 2] killed/failed due to:OTHER_VERTEX_FAILURE]DAG did not succeed due to VERTEX_FAILURE. failedVertices:1 killedVertices:1
at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.waitForOperationToComplete(HiveStatement.java:401)
at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.execute(HiveStatement.java:266)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingStatement.execute(DelegatingStatement.java:291)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingStatement.execute(DelegatingStatement.java:291)
at org.apache.zeppelin.jdbc.JDBCInterpreter.executeSql(JDBCInterpreter.java:718)
at org.apache.zeppelin.jdbc.JDBCInterpreter.interpret(JDBCInterpreter.java:801)
at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.interpret(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:103)
at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$InterpretJob.jobRun(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:633)
at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:188)
at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.ParallelScheduler$JobRunner.run(ParallelScheduler.java:162)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I'm using `HDP-3.0.1.0` with `Ambari`. Here's my current `Hive config`:

```
Tez Container Size: 3072 MB
HiveServer2 Heap Size: 4096 MB
Memory: 819.2 MB
Data per Reducer: 2042.9 MB
```

They are mostly the default values. Any suggestion on which to tweak for optimum performance?

Comment: We also faced the same issue. We have added `export HADOOP_HEAPSIZE=16384`  to hive-env.sh, But our data was not 20TB is is much less couple of GBs